# What are some noticeable differences between Standard German and Bavarian dialects?

Tags: vocabulary, standard-german, bavarian

Like noticeable grammatical, vocabulary, or pronunciation differences for example

Comment: "most people" is maybe a dangerous generalisation. Dialects have been pretty much declining (or, at least, softening) during the last decades, I would assume.

Comment: Low German is diclining since more than 100 years, Middle and Upper German dialects are not.

Comment: The pronunciation part is still a bit broad. But if you want to restrict it to vocabulary (and maybe grammar) that would be a lot better. Reason: Bavarian is one of the ‘corner dialects’, i.e. among the most distant ones from the standard.

Comment: Bavarian is an Upper German dialect, the ones which the "standard" originally was created from by Luther's bible translation. Low German is the most different from "Standard German", as it was never considered for the standard. It's closely related to Dutch and even English.

Comment: @Janka There is no reason to assume Luther chose any standard other than the one from around his home area in Saxonia/Thuringia — which in turn is not exactly close to linguistic Bavaria. Low *and* High German dialects can be equally far from today’s accepted standard. And of course, Dutch was once part of the same dialect continuum, joining onto the North.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High_German_languages cit.: *The High German languages are marked by the High German consonant shift, separating them from Low German and Low Franconian (Dutch) within the continental West Germanic dialect continuum.*

Comment: @Janka Standard German does not use, e.g. *Kchind* or *Akcht* while some Bavarian dialects do — these sound changes would be an integral part of the High German Consonant Shift. On the other hand, *lacking* the shift is a systematic change that can be (mentally) reversed: If a Northerner talks about an *Appel,* I can change that mentally into *Apfel* and understand it. (Also, you should ping with @ followed by username so that I get the message that you are messaging me.)

Comment: @Jan: I did not make up those categories. People in language science did, regardless whether one can make an easy guess from Low German Standard to High German standard. However, as much Bavarian is a corner dialect both in German and in High German, it isn't most distant from High German standard. Low German is. That's a matter of organising this.

Comment: @Janka Note, by the way, I said *among.*

Comment: @Jan: It's among the most distant ones in German as a whole. That's correct. It's among the most distant ones from the center **within** High German/Standard German, which is -odd enough- somewhere in Mainfranken.

Answer (score -5):

[While Germans say it's a dialect…](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bairische_Dialekte)

[…others say it's a whole different language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bavarian_language)

> S' Boarische is a Grubbm vo Dialekt im Sidn vom daitschn Språchraum.
>
> **Da**s B**aye**rische is**t** **eine** Gru**ppe** vo**n** Dialekt**en** im S**ü**d**e**n **des** d**eu**tsch**e**n Spr**a**chraum**s**.

Imagine you have a dumpling in your mouth while saying the second sentence. [^.^;]

Comment: This does not answer the question.

Comment: The main differences can be seen in the example sentence. Different vowels, different diphthongs, dropping the -e/en, dropping/softening hard consonants, sloppyness about the genitive, use of *a* instead of *einer, eine, eines*. This is explained in more detail in the above linked articles. Much more detail than it was asked for.

Comment: –1 for the dumpling.

Comment: The question is about vocabulary, though. This isn't addressed at all in this answer.

Comment: The question is specifically about sound shifts in cognates, and this answer adresses this. The question is about different words, which is also adressed by this answer, *einer, eine, eines -> a*. And I find it pretty disturbing how much outside editing was applied both to the question **and my comments**, to create the fake reality currently discussed about.

Comment: @Janka Only mods can edit comments. If they did, I suspect that there was a very good reason for it.

Comment: And I suspect trusting flags from users, googletranslating anything unintelligible and making the wrong sense of it is a standard mod practice.

Comment: For the records: except for deleting a comment flagged for rudeness, there was no other moderator's editing on this post. The post was flagged by community users for being not an answer. Moderators came to the conclusion that this is a good example where community will judge much better than any moderator with their single binding vote. We hope you all understand.

Comment: For the records: my comment was **about rudeness** and gave a good example how brittle one can be, with the common insult Bavarians use against people from the north when something isn't exactly flattering them. But hey, one can totally create a new reality by deleting posts with their context.

Comment: @Janka: somebody got offended and flagged your comment - usually that's reason enough to remove it. See http://german.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment for more on comments. Any further discussion on this should go to [meta].

Comment: I understand that. I just makes no sense talking about a "record" when you are deleting things from that "record". Either you have a record or you have something you have changed to make it look neat&tidy. You cannot have both. (For the same reason, we strike-through or even only underline things that should be not considered for the result, instead of simply deleting them.)

Comment: I think this is a good answer, which shows that this question cannot be answered so easily by showing these two are very different to one another . +1